# She is so persuasive a girl

Tags: grammar, word-order

I guess the sentence is in correct English grammar and style. But sounds strange to a Brazilian. Can someone tell why the sentence is "more correct" than the following?

> She is a so persuasive girl.

Comment: One might also say "She is such a persuasive girl."

Comment: Both "she is so persuasive a girl" and "she is a so persuasive girl" both sounds strange to me.

Comment: I had read that on Isaac Asimov's Prelude to Foundation. I'm guessing it's right, although strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a slightly uncommon construction, but your alternative is not grammatical at all. That's because *so* here **does not mean** Portuguese *muito* but rather Portuguese *tão*.  This is a common confusion between English speakers and speakers of Iberian languages, because the mapping isn’t what one might otherwise expect.

Think of this as a chopped-off *so . . . as* or perhaps *as . . . as* construction.

Imagine if the phrase had been:

> She is not so persuasive a girl as her sister is.

or even

> She is just as persuasive a girl as her sister is.

(So it works more like *tão . . . como . . .* or *tão . . . quanto . . .* in Portuguese.)

Comment: ........Agreed.

Comment: I wish I could fully understand your answer :)